# Global Full Text Search and Role permissions - multiple products

Tags: elasticsearch, design-patterns, database-design, solr, graphql

I am working on Global Search feature for the Product suite. We have 4 different products, Product A,B,C and D. Each products have their own user rules and those rules defined accessibility to results for the global search.

I want some recommendation what would be the best option for me in terms of technology which is more suitable for this kinds of design problems? 
I did some research on elastic-search - but i am stuck on the part 
how i can apply security rules from all the diff products to filter 
the search result

Any pointers will be really helpful

I have looked into Solr , graph-ql and elastic-search. But that did not answer how can i manage security rules which will be diff for all the products. Not sure how can i consolidate all of them and how can i filter the query results.

I am definitely going to leverage No-SQL as SQL is not right solution for this kinds of problem. However, roles/security is my concern

As a user i should be able to do global search across all the products based on keywords. The results should show data based on user and its security roles and information will be retrieved from all the products based on user role

Just a heads up - i am not allowed to use any cloud technologies like azure, aws etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you know which product the search will be happening then you can have a separate collection of each product. You can index index the attributes/metadata of product along with the user access rules.

If you are not getting the information that which product will be searched upon then you can try to index the product data along with the user access rules.

Here you can use index all the data in single collection and use the sharding and replication feature of solr cloud so the data is distributed and would help you to achieve scalability along with high availability.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The real critical part is, one user can have access to multiple products. Also all the products have diff security and access rules. 

I am trying to figure out to come up with a common database or framework, where other products can push their rules and that platform can be used for the query filter - any suggestion on how can i achieve that?